# How do unit test on 'window.open' (javascript) using sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon, window.open

this is the code I have to test:

```
myFunction: function(data) {
    var file = new Blob(data, {type: 'text/plain'});
    window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
}
```

In order to test it, I thought to test if the window.open function is called, applying a 'spy' on window.open , in the following way:

```
    sandbox.spy(window, 'open');
```

but, even leaving previous line as the unique line in the test, what I only get is the test failure and the following message:

> global leaks detected: consoleLogging, open

Thus, in order to avoid that, I tried to re-define the function in the test in this way:

```
     global.window = {
           open: function (url) {}
     };
```

In this case an exception raised:

> Attempted to assign to readonly property

Then I tried to mock the 'open' via the following:

```
sandbox.mock(window, 'open');
objectUnderTest.myFunction();
expect(window.open.callCount).to.equal(1);
```

this way, I get no global or readonly errors, but an exception on the 'expect', telling that:

> expected undefined to equal 1

Does someone knows a way to successfully test window.open?

Comment: what testing framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the unit test solution based on `Node.js` environment:

`index.js`:

```js
const obj = {
  myFunction: function(data) {
    var file = new Blob(data, { type: 'text/plain' });
    window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
  }
};

module.exports = obj;
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
const obj = require('./');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('53524524', () => {
  before(() => {
    class Blob {}
    global.Blob = Blob;
    global.window = {
      open() {},
      URL: {
        createObjectURL() {}
      }
    };
  });
  it('should test myFunction correctly', () => {
    const openStub = sinon.stub(window, 'open');
    const createObjectURLStub = sinon.stub(global.window.URL, 'createObjectURL').returns('fake object url');
    obj.myFunction('fake data');
    expect(createObjectURLStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(openStub.calledWith('fake object url')).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  53524524
    ✓ should test myFunction correctly


  1 passing (11ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |    66.67 |      100 |                   |
 index.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.js |      100 |      100 |       60 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/53524524